# Cannot perform a function on columns in pandas dataframe with the same name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to take the maximum of columns with the same name with groupby method:

```
df.groupby(by=df.columns, axis=1).max()
```

For example, I have such dataframe:

```
ID A A B B
1  1 2 2 1
2  1 0 0 1
```

I want to get this:

```
 ID A B 
 1  2 2 
 2  1 1
```

Instead, I get this:

```
ID A A.1 B B.1
 1  1 2  2  1
 2  1 0  0  1
```

So, .1 is just added to each duplicated column name, without any maximization.

Comment: are you sure the df columns are duplicated? ideally when reading pandas adds a suffix to them , what is `print(df.columns)` ? if so you can may be try `df.groupby(df.columns.str.replace('.\d+',''),axis=1,sort=False).max()`